# Dynamic Highcharts moving, adding and removing points and series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, draggable

I have been looking at several questions and I haven’t found a solution to my problem.

I want to do the following:

- Add a point to a selected series by clicking on the chart and the point should be sorted
  in on the X axis so the line flows in one direction and not just add
  it to the end of the series.
- remove a point in a series by doubleclick ( however this seems to be very difficult when using drag/drop extension) if it's not possible then remove a selected point with a button.
- drag and drop  points from any series.
- Add and remove series.

I've done several tests in fiddler and if I do them all separately they work fine but when I try to combine them it fails.

here is a test version: http://jsfiddle.net/rDKE3/

```
    var currentIndexSelected;
var data;
data = [
    [1, 29.9],
    [2, 71.5],
    [3, 106.4],
    [4, 129.2],
    [5, 144.0],
    [6, 176.0],
    [7, 135.6],
    [8, 148.5],
    [9, 216.4],
    [10, 194.1],
    [11, 95.6],
    [12, 54.4]
];
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        events: {
            click: function (e) {
                // find the clicked values and the series
                var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                    y = e.yAxis[0].value,
                    series = this.series[0];

                // Add it
                series.addPoint([x, y]);
                // data.addPoint([x, y]);

            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {

    },
    yAxis: {},
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 60,
        x: -60
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {},
    series: [{
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'ns-resize',
        point: {
            events: {
                select: function () {
                    var pId = this.series.data.indexOf(this);
                    currentIndexSelected = pId;


                    $('#out').html(
                        'Dragging <b>' + this.series.points[pId].y); //this.series.data[0].x + '</b>, <b>');

                },

                drag: function (e) {

                    // Returning false stops the drag and drops. Example:
                    /*
                        if (e.newY > 300) {
                            this.y = 300;
                            return false;
                        }
                        */
                    $('#drag').html(
                        'Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.newY, 2) + '</b>');
                },
                drop: function () {
                    $('#drop').html(
                        'In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>');
                }
            }
        },
        data: data,
        //data: [[1,29.9], [2,71.5],[3,106.4], [4,129.2], [5,144.0], [6,176.0], [7,135.6], [8,148.5], [9,216.4], [10,194.1], [11,95.6], [12,54.4]],
        draggableX: true,
        draggableY: true,

    }]
});




// button handler
$('#button1').click(function () {
    //this.point[currentIndexSelected].remove();
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    if (chart.series.length == 1) {
        //chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({
            data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
            draggableX: true,
            draggableY: true
        });
    }




    var series = chart.getSelectedSeries();
    $('#out').html('length:' + series.length);

    data.splice(currentIndexSelected, 1);

    chart.series[1].setData(data);
    chart.redraw();

});

// button handler
$('#button2').click(function () {

    var series = chart.getSelectedSeries();


    data.splice(currentIndexSelected, 1);

    chart.series[0].setData(data);
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);

});
```

Comment: Well, in general Highcharts requires sorted data for xAxis, so adding new point in the middle mean you need to.. set new data using setData().

Comment: Yes I've learned that I need to build a new set of data. But what about the combination of everyting? cant add a point to the second series nor remove points from it. Btw thank you for your comments I was hoping you would find your way here as I've read some of your answers on other topics :)

Comment: to clairify one of the problems a bit more: if you add a point ( in this case at the end) there is a strange offset when trying to remove one of the new points instead another point is deleted. same goes with selecting one of the new points

Comment: First, let's try to make sure data points are sorted, that's what I have done: http://jsfiddle.net/rDKE3/4/ (click to add point). Now, what is wrong? In add series I see you are getting selected series, and then removing some of points from new added series - why?

Comment: Sorry that was an old test I forgot to comment out I commented it: http://jsfiddle.net/3szVY/ so the other issue with choosing which series to add or remove points from ?

Comment: This way you can add double click on a point: http://jsfiddle.net/E9fnA/149/

Comment: why dont you use the event dblclick in your example? your example does not work its never triggered.

Comment: I have added dblclick only for first marker in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/E9fnA/149/ - and the same, first point with added here: http://jsfiddle.net/rDKE3/5/